# div scrolling on hover like in tn3gallery

Tags: jquery, scroll, hover, smoothing

i need to impliment in my gallery thumb scrolling like here: http://www.tn3gallery.com/examples/tn3_eris_horizontal/

I have tried smooth div scroll but this is not exactly what i'm looking for, have some one idea how this is done?

Comment: Can you provide an working sample with what you have tried so for? It will be helpful to answer your question.